# SQL Server 2008 R2 Install Won't Work

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to install the developer edition of SQL Server 2008 R2.  I run the setup as admin, but after it installs the "Setup Support Files", it closes and returns back to the installation center screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you have the file for the correct architecture?

Comment: Have you checked `%TEMP%` for installer log files?

Comment: Orbit - I verified that I have the right install for my system.  I checked the logs and couldn't find anything in there.

Answer (score 11):

I had this same problem and it appears to be something to do with previous versions leaving behind elements in their install/uninstall. I fixed it by running the Microsoft install/uninstall utility linked below. During the process you are asked what program you are trying to install and MSSQL Server 2008 R2 is listed. After running this the install continued after the "Setup Support Files" stage. Hope it helps!

http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall

Answer (score 1):

So does it even installs Support files? You can check it by looking into "Programs and Features" (if using Windows Vista or 7) and if it is not there then it is not even installing support files. In that case may be you are missing components required for Support files itself (e.g. older version of Windows Installer).

Sometimes, SQL Server installer itself acts funny and without any reason it just crashes. Did you tried to run it again? Or try to run the installer *after* rebooting your system (I know this sound like a too rookie advice but in many cases rebooting OS solves issue).

Comment: Please avoid funny thing like ?? and !! write your answers like small articles

Answer (score 1):

The problem started when I change the shared folder directory from \Program Files(86)\SQL Server to custom folder. If I could have rename back to default, it should have been fine but I stop the installation and restart the install again assuming it will install fresh, but it did not and it hangs all the time.

I appreciate the comment from Lee, as per his advice I ran the fix it tool from Microsoft. The tool finds SQL Server 2008 R2 installed and I choose to uninstall.

When re-install the SQL Engine, it went through because this time, I did not change the Share Folder location and leave it to the default. I think this is some kind of bug in the SQL Installation. I wonder why Installation has to hang...!

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the location of the Setup Support Files.

Remove all the Setup Support Files using Control Panel/Uninstall Program.
After that install SQL 2008 from the beginning.